# ion slide with cards animation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tinder

I have following code to swipe cards. Now I want to swipe the cards like Tinder.

How can I implement this in Angular with Ionic?

`<ion-content>
<ion-slides [options]="{ slidesPerView: true, loop: true,  preloadImages: true,
lazy: false}">
<ion-slide *ngFor="let card of cards" >

```
  <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
  
  <ion-card >
    <ion-img  [src]="card.img" alt="The Wisconsin State Capitol building in Madison, WI at night"></ion-img>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>{{card.title}}</ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-subtitle>{{card.description}}</ion-card-subtitle>
    </ion-card-header>
  
    
  </ion-card>

  <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>

</ion-slide>
```

</ion-slides>

</ion-content>`

I want to have a Tinder Swipe in Angular and Ionic

Comment: Don't bother. ion-slides is deprecated. You are better off just doing it with standard slide.js. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides

Comment: ok yes i will do it. Have you got a Tutorial for cards animation with ion slides??

Comment: Just replace the `<h1>` element in the example with `<ion-card>` code https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides#usage